# nslookup fails even though DNS is set to the same server as it should be using

Tags: dns

I have DNS problems resolving local addresses.

nslookup fails for local addresses if not specifying a server to use:

```
$ nslookup nas
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find nas: SERVFAIL
```

here it works when telling it to use `192.168.0.1`:

```
$ nslookup nas 192.168.0.1
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Name:   nas
Address: 192.168.0.11
```

network configuration shows the DNS server in use as being `192.168.0.1`, as does `systemd-resolve --status`.

I changed nsswitch.conf to have only:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

after reading another answer elsewhere but that has had no effect.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 but I don't know if the problem pertains only to this OS.

`/etc/resolv.conf` contains:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search localdomain
```

Comment: What do the `nameserver` lines say in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search localdomain